# What is the difference between __dirname and ./ in node.js?

Tags: node.js

When programming in Node.js and referencing files that are located somewhere in relation to your current directory, is there any reason to use the `__dirname` variable instead of just a regular `./`? I've been using ./ thus far in my code and just discovered the existence of `__dirname`, and essentially want to know whether it would be smart to convert my ./'s to that, and if so, why that would be a smart idea.

Comment: tl;dr: So, basically, the difference is that './' and 'process.cwd()' refer to the current dir of the terminal calling the script, whereas the '__dirname' refers to the dir in which the script is stored.

Comment: _Except_ when `.` is used inside `require`. The path inside `require` is always relative to the file containing the call to `require`.

Answer (score 944, accepted):

## The gist

In Node.js, `__dirname` is always the directory in which the currently executing script resides ([see this](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname)). So if you typed `__dirname` into `/d1/d2/myscript.js`, the value would be `/d1/d2`.

By contrast, `.` gives you the directory from which you ran the `node` command in your terminal window (i.e. your working directory) when you use libraries like `path` and `fs`. Technically, it starts out as your working directory but can be changed using `process.chdir()`.

The exception is when you use `.` with `require()`. The path inside `require` is always relative to the file containing the call to `require`.

## For example...

Let's say your directory structure is

```
/dir1
  /dir2
    pathtest.js
```

and `pathtest.js` contains

```
var path = require("path");
console.log(". = %s", path.resolve("."));
console.log("__dirname = %s", path.resolve(__dirname));
```

and you do

```
cd /dir1/dir2
node pathtest.js
```

you get

```
. = /dir1/dir2
__dirname = /dir1/dir2
```

Your working directory is `/dir1/dir2` so that's what `.` resolves to. Since `pathtest.js` is located in `/dir1/dir2` that's what `__dirname` resolves to as well.

However, if you run the script from `/dir1`

```
cd /dir1
node dir2/pathtest.js
```

you get

```
. = /dir1
__dirname = /dir1/dir2
```

In that case, your working directory was `/dir1` so that's what `.` resolved to, but `__dirname` still resolves to `/dir1/dir2`.

#### Using `.` inside `require`...

If inside `dir2/pathtest.js` you have a `require` call into include a file inside `dir1` you would **always** do

```
require('../thefile')
```

because the path inside `require` is always relative to the file in which you are calling it. It has nothing to do with your working directory.

Comment: I agree. I will change the accepted answer. Please keep in mind that this answer was added 2.5 years after the original one was accepted, and I only just noticed it now (another 2 years later). :) Better late than never!

Comment: It's worth noting that `./` is not *always* the directory that node was launched from.  It starts out that way, but can be changed via `process.chdir()`.  So, `./` is always the current working directory, which is usually the directory node was launched from, unless your code explicitly changed the working directory.

Comment: I am a little confuse about the Using . inside require part, if the path inside require is always relative to the file you are calling, isn't the path should be require('../thefile') instead of require('../dir1/thefile')? i thought the .. bring the current position of the path back one level from dir2 to dir1 already. Do you still need to put dir1 in the path or am i miss understood something?

Comment: And how would you do if you need to use `../someDir` in some script and you're going to run the command from a different folder?

Comment: A note that with ES modules, the `__dirname` global is gone but can be replaced by `import { dirname } from "path";`

Answer (score 161):

`./` refers to the current working directory, except in the `require()` function. When using `require()`, it translates `./` to the directory of the current file called. `__dirname` is always the directory of the current file.

For example, with the following file structure

`/home/user/dir/files/config.json`

```
{
  "hello": "world"
}
```

`/home/user/dir/files/somefile.txt`

```
text file
```

`/home/user/dir/dir.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');

console.log(require('./files/config.json'));
console.log(fs.readFileSync('./files/somefile.txt', 'utf8'));
```

If I `cd` into `/home/user/dir` and run `node dir.js` I will get

```
{ hello: 'world' }
text file
```

But when I run the same script from `/home/user/` I get

```
{ hello: 'world' }

Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory './files/somefile.txt'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:228:18)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:119:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/dir/dir.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Using `./` worked with `require` but not for `fs.readFileSync`. That's because for `fs.readFileSync`, `./` translates into the cwd (in this case `/home/user/`). And `/home/user/files/somefile.txt` does not exist.

Comment: oh i thought __dirname was the current working directory... thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Is there any way to reference the working directory of the app with fs? For example, I'm trying to load a file from the working directory `/movies`, but since my module is in a file `/custom_modules/`, `__dirname` tries to grab the movie from , `/custom_modules/movies`

Comment: You can use `./` or `process.cwd()`. see http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd

Comment: Worth noting it is _not_ a good idea to use __dirname over ./ in require statements because although they behave identically in node, it can cause issues with browserify builds for packages that are easily otherwise avoided.