# NodeJS APN module cannot find certificate file on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I am using the apn module (https://github.com/argon/node-apn) to send push notifications to iPhones from NodeJS.

My code works fine on my development machine (Mac OSX) and is successfully pushing notifications through the Apple sandbox gateway (gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com), but when I move it to the staging server (which is running Ubuntu) pushing notifications fails with the message:

```
 Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'apns-dev-cert.pem'
```

I am setting up the NodeJS apn object as such:

```
var options = {
    cert: "apns-dev-cert.pem",          
    key:  "apns-key.pem",               
    passphrase: null,   
    gateway: "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",              
    port: 2195,                         
    enhanced: true,                     
    errorCallback: undefined,                       
    cacheLength: 5                                  
};
```

On my development Mac OSX machine, the cert is installed in the Keychain. From my limited understanding of Ubuntu, the equivalent would be to copy the cert file to /etc/ssl/certs. I tried doing this, and also changing the path to "/etc/ssl/certs/apn-dev-cert.pem" in my NodeJS code, but the same error message shows up.

Any ideas?

Comment: keep your pem files where you kept the above source file and try!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled a lot with this issue until I realized that I hadn't understood how the `fs` module reads files. Apparently, it reads them from the directory where you started your node process. So the path to your `.pem` files should be relative to wherever you're doing that.

You might wanna [check out](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) `__dirname` too, which might [make it easier to specify your paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js).

Answer (score 0):

You try to setup as below:

```
var options = {
    //cert: "apns-dev-cert.pem",          
    //key:  "apns-key.pem",               
    pfx: '<path>/apns-key.pem',    
    passphrase: null,   
    gateway: "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",              
    port: 2195,                         
    enhanced: true,                     
    errorCallback: undefined,                       
    cacheLength: 5                                  
};
```