# Zero byte files after XML download in node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, npm

I have the following code snippet I am currently employing attempting to get Yahoo weather XML files:

```
// This script requires request libraries.
// npm install request

var fs = require('fs');
var woeid_array = fs.readFileSync('woeid.txt').toString().split("\n");
var grabWeatherFiles = function (array) {
//var http = require('http');
//var fs = require('fs');

array.forEach( 
function(element)  {
    var http = require('http');
    var file_path = 'xml/' + element + '.xml';
    console.log(file_path);
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(file_path);
    var request = http.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=' + element, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);

    });

});

};
grabWeatherFiles( woeid_array );
```

This code snippet is successful at downloading the XML files. However, if I attempt to read the files and get the XML data inside a string so I can parse it, the files are 0'd out. Is node.js not writing this correctly? This happened both on my Mac and on c9.io. Any tips would be lovely. I am quite stuck in this part.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function. [fs.writeFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) takes at least three arguments `filename`, `data` and `callback`. You cannot pipe to it. It simply writes data to the filename and executes callback when done.

What you need is [fs.createWriteStream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options), which takes path (apart from extra options). It creates a writeable stream, to which you can pipe into the response.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I used to do the job and it works. Created a folder named xml in the same level where `*.js` file resides. Created `woeids.txt` file with some valid woeids from http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup/london

created modified version of your code with path definition to use `__dirname` (useful explanation of it : [What is the difference between __dirname and ./ in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js)) and put code in `sample.js`:

```
// This script requires request libraries.
// npm install request

var fs = require('fs');
var woeid_array = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/woeids.txt').toString().split("\n");
var grabWeatherFiles = function (array) {
    array.forEach( 
    function(element)  {
        var http = require('http');
        var file_path = __dirname + '/xml/' + element + '.xml';
        console.log(file_path);
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(file_path);
        var request = http.get('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=' + element, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);

        });

    });
};
grabWeatherFiles( woeid_array );
```

Run it through terminal `node sample.js` and it populated the `xml` folder with the proper xml files.