# how to get source path and destination path in imagemagick?

Tags: node.js, express, path, imagemagick

I have uploaded photo.jpg to `C:/myapp/public/fullsize`. I want to resize this image and put it in `C:/myapp/public/thumb`. I do not know how to get `newPath` and `thumbPath`

```
 C:/myapp/
             server.js
             app/
                 myscript.js
             public/
                 fullsize/
                         photo.jpg
                 thumb/
```

In myscript.js

```
 var path = require('path');
 var im = require('imagemagick');
 var imageName = path.basename(req.files.file.path); //photo.jpg
    var newPath =  ???;
    var thumbPath = ???;
    im.resize({
                  srcPath: newPath,
                  dstPath: thumbPath,
                  width:   200
                }, function(err, stdout, stderr){
                  if (err) throw err;
                  console.log('resized image to fit within 200x200px');
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded files will be located in a temporary location. First you need to move the file to C:/myapp/fullsize. This is explained clearly in this [article](http://howtonode.org/78e21b7d5503a5b2b372f6c2a5de077a1e809267/really-simple-file-uploads).

Your next step would be to get req.files.file.name and create destination path. This can be achieved by using

```
var dstPath = __dirname + "/public/thumb/" + req.files.file.name;
```

Now you can resize image with the correct paths.

Comment: With your way, if I use console.log(dstPath) >> C:/myapp/app/puplic/thumb/photo.jpg. It is wrong because __dirname will respond to C:/myapp/app/

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: Yes, I am using express

Comment: Check this once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js