# Node require path reference issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I am using node to run some JS tasks. I am using node require to include other needed files that I have written.  The files I am trying to include exist in the same directory.  There is nothing special about these files; just plain old JavaScript.  I am not serving the content to a browser or anything.  I am just trying to run JS logic.

My directory structure:

- root

  - exercises

    - ex1

      - FileLoader.js
      - FileOne.js

---

In my FileLoader.js I ran each one of these file path patterns by itself.  They are in the order of my attempts.

```
require('./exercises/ex1/FileOne.js'); // Attempt 1 path
require('FileOne.js'); // Attempt 2 path
require('/exercises/ex1/FileOne.js'); // Attempt 3 path
require('../../exercises/ex1/FileOne.js'); // Attempt 4 path
```

Terminal Command:

```
node ./exercises/ex1/ex1.js
```

Outcomes:

1. Attempt 1 - Error: Cannot find module './exercises/ex1/FileOne.js'
2. Attempt 2 - Error: Cannot find module 'FileOne.js'
3. Attempt 3 - Error: Cannot find module '/exercises/ex1/FileOne.js'
4. Attempt 4 - It worked even though I did not expect to.... FML

So the last one worked but the path needed is pretty silly.  It seems like my app does not have a concept of the root.  I assumed that node thought my root was ex1.  But then I would expect attempt 2 to work.  I feel like I am overlooking something stupid.

Question:

- What is the correct way to use file paths with require?
- Is there a way to set a root directory with node?

Thank you,

Jordan

Comment: I think the right syntax would be `require("./FileOne.js");`...

Comment: Ugg.  Do you want to present that as an answer? Then I can give you credit.

Comment: For future use, this link explains how node.js searches for requires: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax would be `require("./FileOne.js")`. The second form (`require('FileOne.js');`) would work if the file was placed in node path.

To set node root you can use `NODE_PATH`. For example, using

```
NODE_PATH=/path/to/your/project/root node ex1.js
```

you could reference FileOne as:

```
require("exercises/ex1/FileOne.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

Also consider using `__dirname`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js) for better insight. Sometimes referencing might depend on where the node command is called from to start the app when dealing with modules like `fs`. So `__dirname` would be a safe option to use.

> In Node.js, __dirname is always the directory in which the currently executing script resides (see this). In other words, the directory of the script that is using __dirname.
>
> By contrast, . gives you the directory from which you ran the node command in your terminal window (i.e. you working directory). The exception is when you use . with require(), in which case it acts like __dirname.

It's a bit confusing, it is explained clearly in the answer linked.