# Set working directory in gulpfile.js?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Is there a way to set the working directory for Gulp within a gulpfile, so that I can run a gulp command from a subdirectory without running into any issues? I ran a search for this and didn't find what I was looking for.

To clarify, I'm aware of adding a prefix to the files I'm using. However, instead of this -

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
...

var paths = {
    js: [__dirname + 'app/*/*.js', __dirname + '!app/lib/**'],
    css: __dirname + 'app/*/*.styl',
    img: __dirname + 'app/img/*',
    index: __dirname + '*.html',
    dist: __dirname + 'dist'
};
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
...

gulp.cwd(__dirname); // This would be much easier to understand, and would make future edits a bit safer.

var paths = {
    js: ['app/*/*.js', '!app/lib/**'],
    css: 'app/*/*.styl',
    img: 'app/img/*',
    index: '*.html',
    dist: 'dist'
};
```

I'm wondering if Gulp exposes this functionality. Perhaps node itself allows this.

(I realize that there is likely a way to do command line itself when I run the command, but I would like to include it in the gulp file, especially for distribution purposes. I want the working directory for gulp to match the directory in which the gulpfile resides.)

Thanks!

Comment: __dirname http://stackoverflow.com/a/8131696/94144 ?

Comment: That's one way to get the script directory, sure, but how can I set that directory as my working directory? There's `process.cwd()`, but it doesn't look as though I can assign anything through that. Does gulp expose something to let me accomplish this, or is it something that only a node command can offer?

Comment: Doesn't it already do that?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are using Gulp, but it comes with two main methods, src and dest, and you can set both using, let's say path.join(__diename, 'src', 'styles') http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2

Comment: @coma I do know about that possibility, but I was wondering if I could avoid prefixing every directory with `__dirname` and instead do something like `process.cwd = __dirname`. Bower offers this capability in a config file (which, admittedly, is not really the same thing) and so I was wondering if there's a way to be less verbose.

Comment: @coma I've edited the question to hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Comment: What is the particular issue you're running into? By default gulp will set your cwd to the gulpfile.js directory.

Comment: @justinhoward From what I've seen so far, the cwd isn't set to the gulp file directory if you run gulp from a subdirectory in your project. Admittedly, I've probably messed it up somehow....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of concatenating strings by yourself, you should be using [path.join](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2) since it will take care of the proper slash, and following that path you can add a shorcut:

```
var path = require('path'),
    p    = function () {

    Array
        .prototype
        .unshift
        .call(arguments, __dirname);

    return path.join.apply(path, arguments);
};

console.log(p('a', 'b', 'c'));
```

Or, well, you can just:

```
gulp.src(..., {cwd: __dirname})
gulp.dest(..., {cwd: __dirname})
```

Something like:

```
var src = function (globs, options) {

    options = options || {};
    options.cwd = __dirname;

    return gulp.src(globs, options);
};

var dest = function (folder, options) {

    options = options || {};
    options.cwd = __dirname;

    return gulp.dest(folder, options);
};
```

Look [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/index.js#L25-L26) and [here](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs).

Comment: Hmm. This might fit my needs - and it's good to know about the `cwd` argument to `gulp.src` and `gulp.dest`. I generally like to try to keep my gulpfiles short (but readable), but in the event of larger ones I will likely end up using your final methods. Thanks!

Comment: @jedd.ahyoung, you can split your Gulp flows into several files and combine them using closures like https://coderwall.com/p/yzvbvw/defining-and-running-gulp-tasks-for-each-environment-on-the-fly?p=1&q=author%3Acoma

Answer (score 9):

Besides `option.cwd`, you can also use `process.chdir(yourDir)`

it could be used anywhere in a gulpfile. e.g.

```
process.chdir(yourDir);
var gulp = require('gulp');
```

Make sure your gulp is up-to-date( > 3.8.10), this may not work in older gulp.