# fs.readFileSync() fails in express js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

The Structure of my project is:

```
- project
  - routes
     admin.js
     sql-requests.xml
```

Now, in my `admin.js` I am trying to read the `sql-requests.xml` file. Assuming they are on exactly the same path, this is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.readFileSync('./sql-requests.xml');
```

This has failed. Here's the list of what I have attempted:

- `sql-requests`
- `sql-requests.xml`
- `/sql-requests.xml`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will depend on the working directory where you are executing `admin.js` from. If you're looking to access the file next to the current executing script then the following will be more reliable:

```
var content = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/sql-requests.xml');
```

See this answer (and question) for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18283508/112196

Comment: Thank you Pero! In case the location of my file will be one level lower, how can I read it? Assume the file is in project folder, not routes

Comment: To go up use `__dirname + '../sql-requests.xml'` or down `__dirname + 'routes/sql-requests.xml'` for example