# What is the difference between require(__dirname + path) and require(./path)

Tags: javascript, node.js

According to this question: [What is the difference between __dirname and ./ in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js) these 2 lines should be the same:

```
require(__dirname + '/folder/file.js');
require('./folder/file.js');
```

and I always used to use the second option. But now a project, I took over, the previous developer used `require(__dirname + ...)` every time.

Personally I thinks it's harder to read and I'd like to change it, but maybe there is some advantage of this syntax I'm missing? Or is it the preferred version and I was doing it wrong all the time?

Just in case it matters, the libraries run sometimes on node.js with es6 enabled and sometimes on io.js (without additional flags).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `require()` there is no difference, using `__dirname` is kind of redundant. The module loader will take care of the resolving the path correctly for you.

When using one of the `fs` methods like `fs.readFile` there is a difference if your current working directory is not equal to `__dirname`. If I want to read contents of a file called file.txt in the same directory as my script, I do:

```
var Fs = require('fs');
var Path = require('path');

Fs.readFile(Path.join(__dirname, 'file.txt'), ...);
```

Then it doesn't matter what my cwd is when I start the node process that executes this code.