# About node file path?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

If I have some js or css files in the views folder,then how can I write the path to link thoes files?[this is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJS1y.png)

Comment: You need to do some reading. To give you pointers: `__dirname` is a global variable provided by node.js which gives you the directory path that the currently executing script resides in. Refer this [documentation link](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) . Also, refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js) question on why you should use `__dirname` instead of `./`

Answer (score 1):

***you can add the script path into your view file to call them.***

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    if(req.url.indexOf('.js') != -1){ //req.url has the pathname, check if it conatins '.js'

      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/script.js', function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      });

    }

    if(req.url.indexOf('.css') != -1){ //req.url has the pathname, check if it conatins '.css'

      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/style.css', function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
      });

    }

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Thats just to give you and idea !