# NodeJS difficulty serving static content with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I ran a simple NodeJS and Express server on my Windows 10 development machine

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('app'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static('bower_components'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Listening on :3000");
});
```

This works, however when I tried to upload it on my Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) box, only files which are present directly under `/app` will get served, and nothing from the subfolders.

On the linux machine, I noticed I was running node version `v0.10` so I updated to `v4.5.0`. My windows machine runs `v4.4.4`.

I had an idea it might be related to permissions, so I tried setting those, but to no avail.

The file structure looks like this

```
├───api
├───app
│   ├───assets
│   │   ├───css
│   │   └───images
│   └───scripts
│       ├───auth
│       ├───directives
│       ├───filters
│       ├───home
│       ├───i18n
│       └───services
├───bower_components
```

Have anyone been through the same sort of issue?

Comment: can you post the actual file structure of your app?

Comment: @DaveV Updated now

Comment: When you use `chmod` and `chown` on Linux, use the `-R` flag so that the permissions recurse into the sub directories.

Comment: If all of the directory permissions look good, check the permissions of the Node script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you put everything in files good, so only issue, that can be painfull for nodeJS serving like you want is that path is not specified.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

If you do `app.use(express.static('app'));` the dierectory `app` is injected at `/` directory (or execution folder of nodeJs installation in extreme case). The only thing that comes to my mind is to add `__dirname + '/app'` before express.static: `app.use(__dirname + '/app', express.static('app'));`

[`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) is a nodeJS variable in the module's scope that contains the name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in

---

If that is changing something try this to match everything: [What is the difference between __dirname and ./ in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js)