# Reference a pem file in a cloud function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to convert a `firebase-queue` worker to send push notification to a cloud function. I am using `node-apn` to send push notification to iOS devices. It requires setting up a connection which requires me to specify a `key.pem` file and `cert.pem` file. These files are present at the same location where the worker js file is present and works without any problem. I moved over the code to a cloud function but I get this error in the Logs console

```
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './cert.pem'
    at Error (native)
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './cert.pem' } 'Unable to send push notification to iOS device. Socket Error'
```

Below is how the files are specified and the connection is created in the code

```
var connectionOptions = {
  cert:'./cert.pem',
  key:'./key.pem',
  production: true
};

var apnConnection = new apn.Connection(connectionOptions);
```

I have tried specifying the cert file as `./cert.pem` and `cert.pem` but I get a similar error in both the cases. I guess the problem is that the `.pem` files are not shipped along with the functions.

How can I specify such files in a cloud function?

Comment: Any luck with this yet?

Comment: Nope. I haven't found anything to get around this problem yet and am a bit disappointed that no one from firebase team has given any suggestions. I am relying on my queue worker for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path reference isn't quite right for firebase functions.

It should be:

```
var connectionOptions = {
  cert:__dirname + '/cert.pem',
  key:__dirname + '/key.pem',
  production: true
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this also. I didn't find any reference to using `__dirname` when I looked at the firebase functions documentation and I just searched through the documentation and the firebase function samples https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples and don't see any reference to `__dirname`. Would it be possible to share a reference for this change for my and others benefit? Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully this should explain the reason for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference to the stackoverflow question. Learned something new and important today. I apologize that I have not been able to test with the changes you suggested as I am not able to get time off my current assignment.

Comment: I was finally able to test out this change and it works. Thanks!