# Why is the use of __dirname in Node js?

Tags: node.js

I am leaning node js as a beginner.Why we use __dirname in node js when we are reading or writing a file.what is the output of __dirname.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between \_\_dirname and ./ in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

`__dirname` simply returns the directory you are in. We use it when a function requires an absolute path as a parameter (for example `express.static()` requires an absolute path).

We can't always use relative paths, and we just can't count on the fact that our program is always going to be executed from the same location in our computer, so it's basically an equivalent to UNIX's `pwd` command.