# Webpack configuration is not working, path must be absolute

Tags: node.js, reactjs, configuration, webpack

I'm getting an error with my Webpack configuration:

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - `configuration.output.path`: The provided value `"./"` is not an absolute path!

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',
 
   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
 
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },
 
   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
       
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Probably do `require('path').resolve(__dirname, './')`

Answer (score 4):

Your `path` has to be absolute, not relative. To use the current directory, use the variable [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname):

> #### __dirname
>
> The directory name of the current module. This the same as the `path.dirname()` of the `__filename`.
>
> `__dirname` is not actually a global but rather local to each module.
>
> Example: running `node example.js` from `/Users/mjr`
>
> ```
> console.log(__dirname);
> // Prints: /Users/mjr
> console.log(path.dirname(__filename));
> // Prints: /Users/mjr
> ```

Thus, it get's your current directory where the config is stored in as an absolute path and you apply it like so:

```
output: {
   path: __dirname,
   filename: 'index.js',
},
```

(Do note there are differences between `./` and `__dirname` as noted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8131344/5647260). `./` refers to the current directory of the terminal calling the script and `__dirname` refers to the directory the script is stored in.)

Comment: @ThilinaMullewidane If the answer did help, please consider clicking the checkmark next to the answer to accept it for future readers. Glad to help.