# Links to static resources in an HTML page served by nodejs not working

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have got my directory structure like this in a nodejs project

[image: I am serving <code>login_nimda.html</code> from <code>nimda.js</code>]

And here's my `login_nimda.html` snippet with the CSS links:

[image]

**I am serving `login_nimda.html` from `nimda.js` but the associated CSS file isn't loading up.**

As you can see I have used **root-relative path** but I am still not getting any results. The same reason why I had to use the CDN for Bootstrap and couldn't use the downloaded file.

How is it supposed to be? Where am I going wrong with the `href` attribute of the link?

EDIT:
Here's my `nimda.js` snippet that is serving the HTML file `login_nidma.html`

```
router.get('/', function( req, res){
    let html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../static/login_nimda.html'));
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});
```

Comment: Please provide your code, specially the section where you are serving the static files.

Comment: I have already provided the part of the page where it links with the css. The page `login_nimda.html` is just served as a response to a GET request by `nimda.js` present in the routes folder. Nothing special in there.

Comment: I meant your Node.is code.

Comment: @KayvanMazaheri Done.

Comment: are serving the static files such as `.css` files in your node.js server as well? If yes, please provide the related code.

Comment: @KavyanMazaheri No, I am not explicitly serving them as such. I just hoped that the html file would link to those but it seems that the html file which is sent as a response holds no connection back to the server. In this case, how am I supposed to serve the static css and js files alongside the html file?

Comment: What code do you have that is failing to correctly serve static files?

Comment: Inside my `nimda.js` route, I have `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../static')));` to serve my css and js inside the `/app/static` folder.

Comment: @AakashVerma Are you open to suggestions on a better way to organize your files/directories? Asking bc it would affect how I might answer your question. Also, are you using anything inside the `/dist` or `/public` directories?

Comment: @therobinkim No, I am not suggesting anything close to that. I want to serve static files from two different folders `static` and `public`. Doing express.static on both of them in `server.js` works but when I do express.static for `static` folder in `nimda.js`, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the `express.static` middleware to serve static files instead of:

   ```
   router.get('/', function( req, res){
       let html = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'../static/login_nimda.html'));
       res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
       res.end(html);
   });
   ```

   https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
   Don't forget that you can use the `path` module and `__dirname` variable (see **[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js)**) to help tell `express.static(...)` exactly where your static files are.
2. If you want to `app.use(express.static(...))` multiplie times in different files, you need to make sure you're applying the middleware to the same `app` instance. **[I've created a code sample to illustrate.](https://github.com/therobinkim/express-serve-static-files/tree/master/original)** In **[server.js#L10](https://github.com/therobinkim/express-serve-static-files/blob/master/original/server.js#L10)**, I pass in `var app` into the `routes.js` module (which is the equivalent of your `nimda.js`). In **[routes.js#L4](https://github.com/therobinkim/express-serve-static-files/blob/master/original/app/routes/routes.js#L4)**, I am calling `.use()` on the same `var app` as the one created in `server.js`. In your refactored version where you're using `app.use(express.static(...))` in both your `server.js` and `nimda.js`, I'm going to guess that you're creating a new `var app = express()` in each file (which is something we want to avoid).
3. I don't recommend having your static assets split into 2 different locations like you have pictured unless you have a very good reason to do so. **[Keeping them in one central location](https://github.com/therobinkim/express-serve-static-files/tree/master/alternate)** will help you reduce the amount of complexity in your app by ensuring that we don't even need a separate `routes.js` (aka `nimda.js`) file for the functionality you need at the moment.

Comment: I should have had just given you the bounty points for your efforts in creating the code. Point 2 exactly pinpointed the problem when I know how vague my question was. All three points are lovely. Great job, man. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to serve your static files (e.g. `.css` files) as well.

You can use Express's built-in middleware for serving static files, `express.static()`.

Here is basic example:

```
// serve static files in "app/static" with your node.js server
app.use('/static', express.static('app/static'))
```

Now you can access them in browser (and inside your HTML files) from `/static`:

```
<link href="/static/css/login_nimda.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Please read more about `express.static()` and its usage here: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Hey, thanks. I had basically got what I was missing on from the discussion at comments. The scene now is that I have to set the static folder in `server.js` which works. Can you guess why when I try to set it in the `nimda.js` under `routes` folder it doesn't conduct the same?

Comment: @AakashVerma The argument to `express.static()` is a relative path. use `path.join` to pass the desired path. also read the last paragraph of (this)[http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html].

Comment: Sorry to bug you this much, but I have been doing the same way you told me using `path.join` but the issue is that I am unable to do it from `nimda.js`. At `server.js`, `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app/static')));` works fine but not at `nimda.js`. I would just like to know if it's possible to serve from `nimda.js`

Comment: @AakashVerma I think this path is still relative to where this line is being called; so changing it to this might actually do the trick in `nimda.js`: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../static')));`

Comment: So silly of me, I didn't check through `console.log(__dirname)` and there's bad news. I was able to produce same path for `express.static()` (checked it using `console.log`) in both `nimda.js` as well as `server.js` but it turns out that the one in `nimda.js` doesn't work. Don't know why but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Express, you dont have to handle requests to static content at all. Express will automatically return your statics. Just use path to router and folder structure. Such as

**app.use('/my_statics',express.static(__dirname + "/public"));**

if you have a.css at **/public/assets/css/a.css** below works

http://example.com/my_statics/assets/css/a.css

if you have b.html at **/public/assets/b.html** below works

http://example.com/my_statics/assets/b.html

EDIT: I built a similar setup in for my sideproject [DataEndpoints](https://github.com/scetiner/dataendpoints). Check **app.js** for static and router setup. Also check **routers** folder to see how to handle, you may wanna look under **views** folder to how to set static file links

Comment: That's not the issue. It's just that when I set the static folder in route file `abc.js` and when I'm at that route say [http://example.com/abc](), it doesn't serve the static files

Comment: why dont you register your static files to the root express object, setting statics to a express.router object is not a proper way I think

Comment: Can you please demonstrate that? I am open any valid and reliable solution.