# Azure Web App Node deployment, change app root directory?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am trying to deploy a Node app on an Azure App Service, using Github and Kudu, running on Windows. The deployment works and the app is started.

My codebase is organised as follows:

```
/config
/res
/src
package.json
```

and `package.json` contains `node src/start.js`.

The problem I am having is that it seems that on that deployment the root directory for the Node app is `site/wwwroot/src` and not (as on my local machine, or my previous deployment on AWS) `site/wwwroot`. This leads to my code not finding the files inside `/config` or `/res` since the paths used in the code presume that the root is top level, and not inside `/src`  (e.g. `./res/myFile.jpg` will try opening `site/wwwroot/src/res/myFile.jpg` and not `site/wwwroot/res/myFile.jpg`).

I have been looking around but can't find how to change this. Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you referencing the files (e.g. ./, __dirname)? I'm referencing this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js.

Comment: like this for instance:  'res/informationInquiryInternalMail.hbs'

Comment: The problem also is that I use a library that searches configuration files depending on environment variable settings, and that it searches those relative to the project root. So in that case I can't fix it by using __dirname since it is out of my control.
In all the time I used AWS I never encountered this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those wondering: I didn't solve it but a workaround is to put your entrypoint js file in the root directory. So instead of having `node src/index.js` you use `node index.js`, while keeping all your other sources in `/src`.