# Relative path error while executing Node script from another folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I have this script that I need to run with `node` through the CLI.

And this script has a file relative file reference as:

```
files: '../functions/index.js',
```

The the file structure is like this:

```
> buildScripts
    myScript.js
> functions
    index.js
```

When I'm inside the `buildScripts` folder (on terminal) everything works:

`>> C:\MyProjectRoot\buildScripts> node myScript.js`

But when I'm inside the `MyProjectRoot` folder, it throws:

`>> C:\MyProjectRoot> node buildScripts/myScript.js`

> **Error occurred:** Error: No files match the pattern: ../functions/index.js

---

**QUESTION**

How can I run this from `myProject` root folder and still get the correct path?

---

I don't know if it depends on the script / packages that I'm running, so here's the full source code for the script:

**myScript.js**

I'm using the `replace-in-file` package to update some imports. This will be a **postBuild** script at some point.

```
const escapeStringRegexp = require('escape-string-regexp');
const fromPath = './src';
const fromPathRegExp = new RegExp(escapeStringRegexp(fromPath),'g');

const replace = require('replace-in-file');
const options = {
  files: '../functions/index.js',  // <----------------------------------
  from: fromPathRegExp,
  to: './distFunctions',
};

replace(options)
  .then(results => {
    console.log('Replacement results:', results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  })
;
```

Comment: You can use `__dirname` or `__filename` to construct your  relative path using `path` module. See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

Comment: Thanks. I changed the `cwd` (which is the base (except on require) for the `'../../someDir'` notation). So the relative paths are working now. I changed it with `process.chdir(__dirname);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following question (link below) helped a lot (it's **not a duplicate**, though):

[What is the difference between __dirname and ./ in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131344/what-is-the-difference-between-dirname-and-in-node-js)

And here is the working version of the script. It works no matter where you execute it from.

```
const path = require('path');
const escapeStringRegexp = require('escape-string-regexp');
const fromPath = './src';
const fromPathRegExp = new RegExp(escapeStringRegexp(fromPath),'g');

const replace = require('replace-in-file');
const options = {
  files: '../functions/index.js',
  from: fromPathRegExp,
  to: './distFunctions',
};

console.log('This is the __dirname: ' + __dirname);
console.log('This is the __filename: ' + __filename);
console.log('This is process.cwd(): ' + process.cwd());
console.log('This is the ../functions/index.js: ' + path.resolve('../functions/index.js'));


process.chdir(__dirname);
console.log('CHANGED cwd WITH process.chdir');

console.log('This is the __dirname: ' + __dirname);
console.log('This is the __filename: ' + __filename);
console.log('This is process.cwd(): ' + process.cwd());
console.log('This is the ../functions/index.js: ' + path.resolve('../functions/index.js'));

replace(options)
  .then(results => {
    console.log('Replacement results:', results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  })
;
```